# How to get Smart Contract Result data?

Tags: multiversx

Let's say for example we have a transaction with this Input Data and this Smart Contract Result

- Input data: `issueNonFungible@415344@415344`
- Result: `@ok@4153442d383661353439`

It's a simple creation of a new NFT Collection. It can be seen on the devnet at this txHash:
`290498e8730975ea6d2703f4c5e0dc2c657b9480b9afc2a62c4c8818636cf062`

[image: Input Data and Smart Contract Results - Elrond explorer]

I am trying to get the response of the smart contract. This is the code I have now with the consts.walletAddress being the wallet address of the sender of the initial transaction.

```js
var txHash = new TransactionHash("290498e8730975ea6d2703f4c5e0dc2c657b9480b9afc2a62c4c8818636cf062");
var toTest = await this.provider.getTransaction(txHash, new Address(consts.walletAddress), true);
var scResults = await toTest.getSmartContractResults();
console.log(scResults)
```

Here is what the `console.log` outputs:
[image: SmartContractResults]

The problem is that **no data is outputted for the Smart Contract Results** so I can not get the response of the smart contract.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in erdJs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. There is just a small bug in the latest erdjs version that is distributed via npm.

In the `TransactionOnNetwork` class the code in the package currently looks like this:

```js
    static fromHttpResponse(response) {
        let transactionOnNetwork = new TransactionOnNetwork();
        transactionOnNetwork.type = new TransactionOnNetworkType(response.type || "");
        transactionOnNetwork.nonce = new nonce_1.Nonce(response.nonce || 0);
        transactionOnNetwork.round = response.round;
        transactionOnNetwork.epoch = response.epoch || 0;
        transactionOnNetwork.value = balance_1.Balance.fromString(response.value);
        transactionOnNetwork.sender = address_1.Address.fromBech32(response.sender);
        transactionOnNetwork.receiver = address_1.Address.fromBech32(response.receiver);
        transactionOnNetwork.gasPrice = new networkParams_1.GasPrice(response.gasPrice);
        transactionOnNetwork.gasLimit = new networkParams_1.GasLimit(response.gasLimit);
        transactionOnNetwork.data = transactionPayload_1.TransactionPayload.fromEncoded(response.data);
        transactionOnNetwork.status = new transaction_1.TransactionStatus(response.status);
        transactionOnNetwork.hyperblockNonce = new nonce_1.Nonce(response.hyperblockNonce || 0);
        transactionOnNetwork.hyperblockHash = new hash_1.Hash(response.hyperblockHash);
        transactionOnNetwork.receipt = Receipt.fromHttpResponse(response.receipt || {});
        transactionOnNetwork.results = smartContractResults_1.SmartContractResults.fromHttpResponse(response.results || []);
        return transactionOnNetwork;
    }
```

As you can see it tries to parse the SmartContract results from the `results` field in the response.

However it would be correct to parse the `smartContractResults` field instead.

This can also be seen in the official [github](https://github.com/ElrondNetwork/elrond-sdk-erdjs/blob/main/src/transactionOnNetwork.ts#L73) where this issue seems to be already fixed.

So for now you can either manually patch the `transactionOnNetwork.js` file in your `node_modules` to use `smartContractResults` or you downgrade to a lower version until this issue is resolved in the latest npm package.